# PHP- Updating a record by ID

Tags: php, sql

So basically I have a table with lecturers and their details. There are two options to either delete or edit the record. I have managed to get delete to work, but not edit the record. When I click edit, my edit user form comes up, but I can't get it to save the changes to my database. It also doesn't output my unsuccessful message or anything, just goes back to the table again.

Here's my code

**Edit user form**

```
    <form class="register" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <div>
            <h2>Edit Lecturer Form </h2>
            <table class="form">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>

                            <span>First Name</span><input name="lectFirstName" type="text" required="true" title="First Name (up to 45 Characters)" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9óáéí']{1,48}">
                            <span>Last Name</span><input name="lectLastName" type="text" required="true" title="Last Name (up to 45 Characters)" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9óáéí']{1,48}">
                            <span>Password</span><input name="lectPass1" type="password" required="true" title="Password (min 5 to 8 Characters)" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9_]{5,8}">
                            <span>Re-enter Password</span><input name="lectPass2" type="password" required="true" title="Password (5 to 8 Characters a-z,A-Z,0-9 and underscore)" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9_]{5,8}">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <span>Hit Enter to finish</span>
                            <input name="send" type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Enter">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**edit code**

```
$table='lecturer';  
$PK="LectID";

    if(isset($_POST['editRecord'])) //edit button has a name of editRecord
    {
        if(isset($_POST['send'])) //send button in edit user form has name of send
        {

            $selectedID=$_POST['LectID'];



            $lectFirstName=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lectFirstName']);
            $lectLastName=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lectLastName']);
            $pass1=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lectPass1']);
            $pass2=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lectPass2']);

            if ($pass1===$pass2)
            {
                $sqlUpdate="UPDATE $table SET FirstName='$lectFirstName', LastName='$lectLastName', password='$pass1' where $PK='$selectedID'";
                if(queryEdit($conn,$sqlInsert)==1) 
                {
                    echo "<h3>New data inserted successfully</h3>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<h3>Edit unsuccessful</h3>";
                }

            }

            else
            {
                echo "<p>Passwords dont match - data not entered";
            }

            $sqlData="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE LectID='$lectID'";  //get the data from the table
            $sqlTitles="SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";  //get the table column descriptions

            //execute the 2 queries
            $rsData=getTableData($conn,$sqlData);
            $rsTitles=getTableData($conn,$sqlTitles);

            //check the results
            $arrayData=checkResultSet($rsData);
            $arrayTitles=checkResultSet($rsTitles);

            //use resultsets to generate HTML tables
            generateTable($table, $arrayTitles, $arrayData);

            //close the connection
            $conn->close();
        }

            include 'FORMS/editUserForm.html';

    }
    else //this is the first time the form is loaded
    {
        //display table with delete options
        //Query string

        $sqlData="SELECT * FROM $table";  //get the data from the table
        $sqlTitles="SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";  //get the table column descriptions


        //execute the 2 queries
        $rsData=getTableData($conn,$sqlData);
        $rsTitles=getTableData($conn,$sqlTitles);

        //check the results
        $arrayData=checkResultSet($rsData);
        $arrayTitles=checkResultSet($rsTitles);

        //use resultsets to generate HTML tables with DELETE button
        generateDeleteEditTable($table, $PK, $arrayTitles, $arrayData);

        //close the connection
        $conn->close();
    }
```

**Edit record button**

```
   <form class="small_button" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <button class="smallBtn" name="editRecord" type="submit" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $buttonText; ?></button>
    </form>
```

**Query Edit Function**

function queryEdit($connection,$sql)

```
{
    try {
        if ($connection->query($sql)===TRUE)  //execute the insert sql
        {
            return 1;  //if successful
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;  //if not successful
        }
    }
    //catch exception
    catch(Exception $e) {
        if (__DEBUG==1)
        {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
            exit('<p class="warning">PHP script terminated');
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location:".__USER_ERROR_PAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `update ... where $PK='$selectedID'` ... what's `$PK`, I can't see it being set?

Comment: There isn't even a `LectID` name attribute or `editRecord` to go with those POST arrays.

Comment: I cna't see the `Edit Record` button either that you speak of. You have a plethora of missing variables.

Comment: Please don't let `$table` be user input.

Comment: Editted to add more information

Comment: We don't really know what your `queryEdit` function does. Also you should escape or typecast `$selectedID` to `int`, if you want to avoid SQL injection in it. I see you're escaping all the other parameters, so they're safe at least. You can try checking for errors using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php

Comment: @coladict Thanks, I added my queryEdit function in. I'll try using that for checking for errors now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the ID of the record to be edited in the form (in a `<input type="hidden" name="LectID" ... />` field). The server needs to know what ID to edit when the form data arrives from the client.

Comment: You may be in for a bit of a long haul here. Go over their code again.

Comment: @Fred-ii- True, but I think the crucial part is for OP to understand the basic data life cycle and that when working in a stateless environment, they need to send the client all data that they'll need when processing a subsequent workflow step.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="small_button" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <button class="smallBtn" name="editRecord" type="submit" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $buttonText; ?></button>
</form>
```

In your form you don't have any HTML element named "send".

Your PHP code will be only executed if `isset($_POST['send']`